# Importing Python packages with same name

Tags: python, import, package

I have two packages installed with the same name, one globally and one locally (a development version). My PYTHONPATH has to local directory in it. Now, when importing in Python, I want to choose which package I take. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Consider using a virtualenv instead of trying to perform hacks like this on the python code level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is giving the local package a different name and then using `import foo_dev as foo` instead of just `import foo`

Comment: I now that this is really a beginner's question, but how can I gave the package a different name?

Comment: Rename the folder where the package is located.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Simplest solution is often best. Good call. +1 to answer and comment.